# Program looking for method in wrong location

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, unrecognized-selector

I am working on a split view controller app, i have two views, a detail view and a second view. When a value on my first view is selected. (say we select dog). my second view loads a few options on the left pane. Therefore from that left pane when i select Color. I want my uilabel to read."Dog is Black"  or if I had selected cat from the first view, i want it to read Cat is yellow. when i select color.

So what i did is, in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath i have

```
if ([[animalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]isEqualToString:@"dog"] )
   {

       secondView *detailList=[[secondView alloc]init];
       [self.detailViewController.navigationController pushViewController:detailList animated:YES];
       self.activeOption=@"dog";
       //defined as @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *activeOption; in .h file
}
```

Then in my secondView i have ( tried to extract the most important things 
.h file

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
   if ([self. detailViewController.activeOption isEqualToString:@"dog"]) {
          self.labelOne.text=@"The Dog is Black";
    }
}
```

Now my problem is, when i click the row to load the second view (dog) i get this error.-[secondView activeOption]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .
Now i believe you get that when you call a method that doesn't exist, so while the method does exist, it doesn't exist in secondView but in the DetailView So i am at a lost as too why it is looking there for the method. even if i said self.detailviewController.
Thanks

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` And take a look at `self.detailViewController`  Is it nil?  Think about where you are setting the `detailViewController` property. It probably isn't set when `viewDidLoad` runs. You could access it in `viewWillAppear` Or write a custom setter and update your option when the property changes

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, self.detailviewController activeOption is nil. Are u saying i should move self.detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
 too viewWillAppear?

Comment: @Paulw11 Moved the above method too my viewWillAppear but samme results, however added a breakppoint to objectAtIndex (Method in orginal code) where i call my secondView and activeOption has its string

Comment: I try and avoid code that introspects the view hierarchy. It is tricky at best and can be fragile in the case of version changes. It is preferable to set the property from the detail view controller on the destination view controller when you are presenting it. Are you using storyboards?  If so you can do it in prepareForSegue

Comment: @Paulw11 I wouldnt say I am using storyboard in the strictest sence, but the project is xcode 5 so storyboard was created by default and the master and detailview controller is both linked to the storyboard. and my secondview is a nib file that gets called.

Comment: @Paulw11 Can i just add my existing nib to the storyboard? and call it from there?

Comment: You can copy the nib in - http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=3834 but you still have to make sure everything connects up properly.